# Are all subsets of NP-complete languages also NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete

Is the following assertion true or false?

> If the language $L$ is NP-complete and $Q ⊆ L$, then $Q$ is NP-complete.

I know for example that $k$-coloring is NP-complete if I take $k$ as input, but 2-coloring is an infinite subset of this which is in P (see [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/71805/can-a-subset-of-an-np-complete-problem-be-in-p)). Therefore, for me, the assertion is *false*. However, I'm working through languages, and I cannot figure out an example (with language) useful to show false the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any infinite NP-complete language $L$. The language $L$ has uncountably many subsets, and particular there is some uncomputable subset $Q \subseteq L$. Since $Q$ is uncomputable, in particular it is not in NP, and so not NP-complete.

You can also try your example. Let $L$ consist of all pairs $(G,k)$ such that $G$ can be colored using at most $k$ colors, and let $Q$ consist of all pairs $(G,2)$ such that $G$ is bipartite; note that $Q \subseteq L$. It is known that $L$ is NP-complete, whereas $Q$ is in P. Therefore $Q$ is not NP-complete unless P=NP.

Comment: Fimus is 2SAT (in P) a subset of SAT (NP-Complete)? if yes I can use as example!

Comment: A language $L_1$ is a subset of a language $L_2$ if every $x \in L_1$ satisfies $x \in L_2$.

Comment: this means the 2SAT is not a subset of SAT

Comment: SAT consists of all satisfiable CNFs. 2SAT consists of all satisfiable 2CNFs. A satisfiable 2CNF is also a satisfiable CNF.

Comment: Sorry now, I'm a little bit confused. If you write "A satisfiable 2CNF is also a satisfiable CNF" for me means 2SAT (P) is a subset of SAT (NP-complete)? from your sentence I understand (if I do not wrong) 2SAT is a subset of SAT

Comment: There really isn’t much more that I can say.

Comment: Yuval, I found the Empty set is a subset of L. I know thet Empty set is P. Can I use as example?